# How to access user defined methods of widget parent

Tags: qooxdoo

I have a parent widget which extends Window class (qx.ui.window.Window) and this window now has couple of children (I have created the children by overriding **childControlImpl**).

Now I would like to access my methods in Parent class from one of the child classes. I don't want to create an object to call the methods, instead I would like to use **getLayoutParent** method to do this.

But when I can call **getLayoutParent** method from the child class, all I can access are the built-in methods, but I can't access any methods which I have created.

How can I get to do this ?

code Sample:

```
qx.Class.define("project.WrkAttrWindow",{

extend : qx.ui.window.Window,

construct: function() {
    this.base(arguments);
    this.__table = this._createChildControl("table");
},
members: {

__table:null 

_createChildControlImpl : function(id)
{
  var control;
  switch(id)
  {
  case "table":
      control = new project.WrkAttrTable();
      this.add(control);
      break;
  }
 return control || this.base(arguments, id);
},

getPrjId:function() {
console.log(I want to call this function);
}
});
```

**Child  Widget**

```
qx.Class.define("project.WrkAttrTable",{

extend: qx.ui.table.Table,

statics: {
    colKeys:["id","name","description"]
},

construct: function() {

    this.base(arguments);
          //some code here
    },

    members:
    {
       //call parent method from here
       this.getLayoutParent().getPrjId(); // does not work
    }
    });
```

Comment: The question is also asked on nabble.com see: http://qooxdoo.678.n2.nabble.com/How-to-access-user-defined-methods-of-widget-parent-tp7584648.html

Answer (score 0):

Despite the cross-post on Nabble, here is the gist from the [answer](http://qooxdoo.678.n2.nabble.com/How-to-access-user-defined-methods-of-widget-parent-tp7584648p7584649.html):

In _*createChildControlImpl*, use **this._add** instead of this.add.

Comment: Since I could not get an answer here, I posted the same on Nabble. And since Christian has already commented on the question with the link, I did not bother to add the answer. But thanks for doing it.